# I am trying to select element with beautifulsoup but it gives my none even though the element exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried many other solution like Xpath try even get the parent div my me the same massage i don't know what to do else.

this is the link: [https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/umErRniA2Sld-Senior-Full-Stack-Python-Developer-Luftborn-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|navbl](https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/umErRniA2Sld-Senior-Full-Stack-Python-Developer-Luftborn-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python%7Csearch-v3%7Cnavbl)

```
my code
result = requests.get(link)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,"lxml")
par_salary = (soup.find('span',{'class':'css-4xky9y'}))
print(par_salary.text)
```

and the output
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\Work\pro1\pro1.py", line 40, in 
print(par_salary.text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: what makes you so sure it exists? *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* What do you find in your `soup` /`result` if you print it?

Comment: Going with @HedgeHog when getting the content from requests the class attribute css-4xky9y does not exist in the response result. Would recommend using something like selenium to load the page to get the content that you are looking for as the content is not sent in the initial request that you are looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are trying to find is not actually in the html originally, but added with JavaScript. You can see this if you disable JavaScript on the page. You can use `selenium` library to get around this.

To install `selenium`, using the command line type:

```
pip install selenium
```

This will do what you want:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/umErRniA2Sld-Senior-Full-Stack-Python-Developer-Luftborn-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python%7Csearch-v3%7Cnavbl"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)

src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
par_salary = soup.find('span', {'class': 'css-4xky9y'}).text
print(par_salary)
```

Answer (score 2):

Content is rendered dynamically by the browser so you will not get a propper result the way you look for the data. You could use `selenium` to mimic a browser and its behavior to get the source you expect or you check the scripts for your expected information

```
import requests, re, json
r = requests.get('https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/umErRniA2Sld-Senior-Full-Stack-Python-Developer-Luftborn-Cairo-Egypt?o=1&l=sp&t=sj&a=python|search-v3|navbl').text
    
list(
    json.loads(
        re.search(r"Wuzzuf.initialStoreState = ({.*}});", r).group(1)
    )['entities']['job']['collection'].values()
)[0]['attributes']
```

Simply pick from the `dict`:

```
{'jobType': 'job', 'applicationType': 'internal', 'status': 'active', 'title': 'Senior Full Stack Python Developer', 'description': '<ul><li>Design, develop and maintain products using front-end/backend web technologies, databases, and cloud services.</li><li>Collaborate with other development teams to establish technology standards and best practices.</li><li>Identify and embrace innovative technologies to enhance customer experience, improve platform stability, scalability, and availability.</li><li>Assist in designing and developing new products and enhancements based on evolving business needs.</li><li>Evaluate innovative technologies, prototype solutions, and conduct knowledge sharing sessions.</li></ul>', 'requirements': '<ul><li>Bachelor of Computer Science or equivalent.</li><li>5+ years of experience in Python development.</li><li>Expert knowledge of programming concepts and object-oriented programming.</li><li>Experience in using software development tools such as JIRA, Confluence, GIT/Bitbucket and Jenkins.</li><li>An understanding of Architecture patterns: microservices, scaling, load balancing.</li><li>Deep knowledge of web development technologies and frameworks.</li><li>Experience with build automation, test-driven development, configuring CI\\CD, Git flow variants.</li><li>Experience working in an Agile team, Scrum preferred.</li><li>Comfortable working with multiple database systems and architectures (SQL, NoSQL).</li><li>Proficiency with front-end languages such as HTML, CSS, and TypeScript/JavaScript.</li><li>Strong analytical and problem-solving abilities.</li><li>Strong communication skills and interpersonal skills.</li></ul>', 'salary': {'min': None, 'max': None, 'currency': None, 'period': None, 'additionalDetails': None, 'isPaid': True}, 'keywords': [{'name': 'Python', 'browsePage': 'a/Python-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'Computer Science', 'browsePage': 'a/Computer-Science-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'Software', 'browsePage': 'a/Software-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'Software Development', 'browsePage': 'a/Software-Development-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'python development', 'browsePage': 'a/Python-Development-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'HTML', 'browsePage': 'a/HTML-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'CSS', 'browsePage': 'a/CSS-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'JavaScript', 'browsePage': 'a/JavaScript-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, {'name': 'SQL', 'browsePage': 'a/SQL-Jobs-in-Egypt'}], 'careerLevel': {'id': 6, 'name': 'Experienced', 'hint': 'Non-Manager', 'browsePage': 'a/Experienced-Jobs-in-Egypt'}, 'location': {'country': {'id': 56, 'name': 'Egypt', 'code': 'EG'}, 'city': {'id': 1545, 'name': 'Cairo', 'latitude': '30.05075900', 'longitude': '31.23383900'}, 'area': {'id': 40, 'name': 'Heliopolis', 'latitude': '30.09257500', 'longitude': '31.32104600'}}, 'workExperienceYears': {'min': 5, 'max': 8}, 'vacancies': 1, 'workRoles': [{'id': 16, 'name': 'IT/Software Development', 'browsePage': 'a/IT-Software-Development-Jobs-in-Egypt'}], 'workTypes': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'full_time', 'displayedName': 'Full Time', 'browsePage': 'a/Full-Time-Jobs-in-Egypt'}], 'schools': [], 'candidatePreferences': {'gender': None, 'educationLevel': {'id': 10, 'name': 'Not Specified'}, 'requiresBachelorDegree': False, 'requiresGoodProfileMeter': False, 'requiresAcademicExcellence': False}, 'hotScore': 0, 'logo': None, 'slug': 'umErRniA2Sld-Senior-Full-Stack-Python-Developer-Luftborn-Cairo-Egypt', 'uri': 'jobs/p/umErRniA2Sld-Senior-Full-Stack-Python-Developer-Luftborn-Cairo-Egypt', 'views': 84, 'redirectUrl': None, 'tempWorkingFromHome': False, 'hideCompany': False, 'hideGender': False, 'hideSalary': True, 'settings': {'isAutoPosted': None, 'isHighlighted': None, 'isFeatured': None}, 'postedAt': '03/14/2023 15:47:48', 'expireAt': '05/13/2023 15:47:48'}
```

Comment: how this is work

Comment: What exactly, could you go more in detail, please? Check the source for `Wuzzuf.initialStoreState` and you will get the `script` with the JSON, the rest is navigating the in JSON / DICT.

Comment: I don't understand what this part do
json.loads(
        re.search(r"Wuzzuf.initialStoreState = ({.*}});", r).group(1)
    )['entities']['job']['collection'].values()
)[0]['attributes']

Comment: Exactly what I wrote - Searching for the script `re.search()` extracting its content `.group()` convert to string to JSON `json.loads()`. The rest is navigating the https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries / JSON by key